# Using enums in Java across multiple classes

Tags: java, class, enums

I have the following class:

```
public class Card 
{
    public enum Suit 
    {
        SPACES, HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS
    };

    public Card(Suit nsuit, int nrank)
    {
        suit = nsuit;
        rank = nrank;
    }

    private Suit suit;
    private int rank;
}
```

I want to instantiate it in another class, but that class doesn't understand the `Suit` enum. Where should I put the enum to make it publicly visible?

Comment: BTW, the `;` after your Suit decl is unnecessary.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Put Suit in its own class:

Suit.java:

```
public enum Suit 
{
    SPACES, HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've been thinking about that but I thought that all classes needed the class keyword.

Comment: @Richard - Yeah, it was surprising to me the first time I saw it.

Comment: This does solve the problem, but I don't think it's the best solution. The Suit enum belongs in the Card class, since you'll always use them together.

Answer (score 31):

The Suit enum is inside the Card class, and you have to access it that way:

```
new Card(Card.Suit.SPADES, 1);
```

Or, you can import the Suit class from within Card, and access it directly:

```
import my.package.Card.Suit;
new Card(Suit.SPADES, 1);
```

The other option is to put Suit in its own class, as suggested by Bert.

Answer (score 6):

The enum is already visible.

```
Card card = new Card(Card.Suit.CLUBS, 5);
```

will instantiate a new card.

Unrelated... but you might want to make the Spaces suit into the Spades suit. :)

Answer (score -5):

The `Suit` enum is inside the `Card` class, and you have to access it that way:

```
Card.Suit suit = Card.Suit.CLUBS;
```

Comment: error: unexpected type
required: class,package
found:    variable